# Javascript - como introducir un setInterval a una promesa

Tags: javascript, promesas, setinterval

Vereis acabo de aprender a crear promesas y he aprendido como crearlas con setTimeout, en plan le introduzco una frase  y un contador y luego hago el then y el catch, hasta ahi bien pero no tengo claro como realizar con setInterval ya que en algun momento debo para la ejecucion y no tengo muy claro donde insertar esto.

```js
var promesa = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Bienvenido!"), 1500);
    setTimeout(() => reject("Algo ha fallado"), 10000);
  });
  
  promesa
    .then((respuesta) => {
      console.log(respuesta);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Por ejemplo si en vez de un mensaje quisiera contar una cuenta en plan 1,2,3,4,5,6 y al llegar a 7 hacer el clearInterval con un if(contador == 7) {clearInterval()}
No se muy bien como realizar esto.

Comment: Las promesas solo se pueden resolver una vez. Lo que tu buscar es un observable. Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760290/4326551) para más información.

Comment: he visto esa respuesta antes pero me ha parecido muy compleja para lo que yo se realizar en estos momentos :( por eso buscaba una explicacion mas sencilla a ser posible en español

Comment: Como ya te han dicho, una promesa **solo se puede resolver una vez**. Si quieres lograr ese resultado sin usar un Observable, tendrías que devolver una nueva promesa con cada interval, o sea, devolver una promesa de promesas xD.

Comment: Te sugiero que leas sobre el patrón observer; te ayudará a entender cómo funcionan los observables.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres mostrar un saludo en 7 segundos (ó x tiempo).
Esto es simplemente una función con setInterval para realizar esa tarea:

```
// la base del conteo es 7 
//(ó cualquier otro número)
var counter = 7;

setInterval(function() {

 if (counter == 0) {

  // Aqui se ejecuta o se muestra contenidos
  document.querySelector("#ver").innerHTML = ("Hola  Mundo!");  

 } else {
  // inicia la cuenta regresiva
  counter = counter -1;
  // se muestra el contador en un id o class
  document.querySelector("#ver").innerHTML = counter;  

 }

}, 1000); // tiempo real del contador
```

Comment: En el mismo id o class que muestras tu saludo (en el if), debes mostrar tu contador (en el else).